# Hikari: Failed to validate connection because connection is closed

Tags: java, database, hikaricp

I'm using hikari pool connection through play framework and mariadb client and since I've updated them (play 2.6.5 -> 2.6.6 and mariadb 2.1.1 -> 2.1.2 but not sure it's related) regularly I've got the following error:

```
HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection@31124a47 (Connection.setNetworkTimeout cannot be called on a closed connection)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.isConnectionAlive(PoolBase.java:184)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:172)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:146)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:85)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:142)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.withConnection(Databases.scala:152)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.withConnection(Databases.scala:148)
```

I've found a related issue [here](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/917) and tried to change the idleTimeout and maxLifetime to 2 and 5 minutes but the error still happened.

I'm using HikariCP 2.7.1, play 2.6.6 and mariadb-java-client 2.1.2

Comment: Hey @Maxence, did you figure out how to fix it?

Comment: @jNewbie, no...

Comment: I tried to change my driver to use the mysql one but still not working

Answer (score 18):

Although you write that you had no success solving this issue by changing the `maxLifetime` value, I wanted to note that it actually worked for me. Putting its value to `590000` has removed the warnings from my log file.

The `maxLifetime` (in milliseconds) value of your client should be less than the `wait_timeout` (in seconds) value of your MySQL instance. This way the client will always terminate the connection before the database tries to. The other way around, the client will try to act upon a closed connection and you will get the above mentioned warnings in your log file.

To see the `wait_timeout` value of your MySQL instance, you can use the following query:

`SHOW VARIABLES like '%timeout%';`

The default `maxLifetime` value for MariaDB should be `28800`, but I noticed that `600` can be in place because of MySQL config files being loaded.

I should note that I have no other explicit hikari configuration in place except for a `maximum-pool-size` of `50`.

I got the inspiration from: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/856 by the way. Other very useful resources are: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby and https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#wait_timeout

Comment: In this case i have configured wait_timeout higher value. But i confused whether it is GLOBAL or SESSION variable in mysql. Only GLOBAL i could change.

Answer (score 1):

Try to configure "keepaliveTime" configuration.

spring.datasource.hikari.keepaliveTime=240000

*"This property controls how frequently HikariCP will attempt to keep a connection alive, in order to prevent it from being timed out by the database or network infrastructure. This value must be less than the maxLifetime value. A "keepalive" will only occur on an idle connection. When the time arrives for a "keepalive" against a given connection, that connection will be removed from the pool, "pinged", and then returned to the pool. The 'ping' is one of either: invocation of the JDBC4 isValid() method, or execution of the connectionTestQuery. Typically, the duration out-of-the-pool should be measured in single digit milliseconds or even sub-millisecond, and therefore should have little or no noticeable performance impact. The minimum allowed value is 30000ms (30 seconds), but a value in the range of minutes is most desirable. Default: 0 (disabled)"*

https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby

Comment: it worked, my MySQL's `wait_timeout` is 28800 (8 hours), while Hikari's `maxLifetime` default is 1800000 (30 minutes), but still has error until set `keepaliveTime=60000`